# How can I record the "resolution" of non-conflict merges?

Tags: git, git-merge, git-rebase

I know that I can use `rerere` to record the resolution of merges *with conflicts*.

But that doesn't help me in my current situation:

I had an experimental branch which I merged into my main branch using `--strategy ours`, discarding any changes I made there, but keeping all the history for future reference. The changes in the experimental branch were unrelated to any changes in the main branch, so there were *no conflicts* and thus `rerere` didn't record anything.

Now I want to rebase this part of my history (using `--preserve-merges`), but since there was no conflict, Git happily replays the merge using the *default strategy*, instead of the *ours* strategy that I originally used. Now all the changes from the obsolete experimental branch end up in my rebased main branch (but I want them to be discarded again).

How can I teach Git to remember the merge strategies I used and re-use them when rebasing?

Comment: You can't: merges do not record the `-s` argument used anywhere.  This is a sort of minor flaw in Git since, as you have seen, `git rebase --preserve-merges` must re-*perform* the merges.  You can, of course, manually mark your merges somehow (with the commit message, for instance) but the rebase script won't notice, so you'd need to write your own rebase script too.

Answer (score 1):

You probably could run `git rebase -p -i` (interactive) and replace picking merges with manual `exec git merge -sours ...` calls. Note I did not test if it works.

Comment: That would probably work, although I would have to remember doing it everytime I rebase, and I won't immediately notice when I forget it. That's why I want Git to remember it for me ;)

Answer (score 1):

You could also use script [git-rehi](https://github.com/max630/git-rehi) (**disclaimer**: written by me) which has exactly this feature: it detects `ours` merges (by comparing tree hashes) and replays them as `ours`

There are also other tools around: [git-reintegrate](https://github.com/felipec/git-reintegrate), [git-remerge](https://github.com/iarna/git-remerge) etc. which you could check if they do it.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're looking to force a recursive merge. You can do this by adding `--no-ff`, and a merge commit will be made.

> --no-ff
>
> Create a merge commit even when the merge resolves as a fast-forward. This is the default behaviour when merging an annotated (and possibly signed) tag.

*from [git-scm documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge)*

Comment: What you describe is an option for the `merge` command. But I'm having problems while doing a `rebase`. The existing merge commit is already recreated, but with the wrong merge strategy.

Comment: Ah, I see, apologies for misunderstanding.